# Variables/Events across multiple jQuery Scripts

Tags: javascript, web-applications, jquery

I am working on a larger web app, made of multiple components that can exist on a page altogether or individually. The parent AppView element must exist for event delegation purposes.

Here is how event delegation is set up:

```
//inside controlsView.js
appView.view.trigger('eventOccured');

...

//later on in controlsView.js
$(document).on('eventOccured', appView.view, function(){
    controlsView.doSomething();
});


//inside ChartView.js
$(document).on('eventOccured', appView.view, function(){
    chartView.doSomething();
});
```

appView, controlsView, and chartView are seperate .js files, but even with a global appView variable, the other .js files don't detect the event being triggered. Is my problem with how I'm trying to trigger/detect custom events on appView.view (the jQuery object for the parent HTML element the app sits inside)?

Here is the real-world example code:

```
//*************** controlsView.js
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var controlsView = {
        initialize: function(){
            var self = this;
            console.log('hi');
        }
    }

    $(document).on('loadControls', appView.view, function(){
        console.log('hi');
        controlsView.initialize();
    });
});

//*************** appView.js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    appView = {
        initialize: function(){
            appView.view = $('#interactiveChartContainer');
            if ($('#graphControls').length){
                appView.view.trigger('loadControls');
            }
        }
    }

    //if the containing element is missing, don't bother loading the rest of the app
    if (!($('#interactiveChartContainer').length)){
        return;
    } else {

        //only run this app if the right element exists on the page.
        appView.initialize();

    }

});
```

Comment: is `appvView.view` part of the DOM?

Comment: essentially the idea is you don't need to delegate if you have direct access to it already. http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/QE9fV/1/

Comment: @KevinB, yes - appView.view exists as an HTML element on the page:
`<div id='interactiveChartContainer'></div>`. I'm adding to the original question to include a more relevant code example.

Comment: In that case the correct .on delegate syntax would be `$(document).on('eventOccured',  '.interactiveChartContaner', ...)`, but it doesn't make sense to do that assuming you have direct access to `appView.view` already, you can bind directly to it.

Comment: The question remains: why are you using event delegation? The element exists, and you have a reference to it. Just do `appView.view.on('loadControls', function() {...});`

Comment: @KevinB, if I had to guess it's because I'm having scope issues since the App is split out into multiple JS files (with multiple `$(document).ready()` functions.

Comment: @JasonP that's actually how the code is currently written (and it does work), but it is a new requirement that the single App.js file be split into multiple, independent .js files. I want to use event delegation as a way for the multiple components to communicate with each other, without inherently assuming that the other components exist. By just pinging the appView.view with a custom event/data, all the individual views can carryout their own functionality without knowing/caring about the other components. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you're having scope issues, then you aren't defining it globally, or it's being included out of order. If you want to not have to worry about that, you'll need to delegate to the classname of the element rather than the possibly undefined appView.view.

Comment: @KevinB if you write this as the answer, I'll select as the correct answer. I just was loading the files in the correct order, appView was self-triggering an event before controlsView's file had loaded, so no listener existed yet to register the event. Just by switching the order in which I loaded the files, the issue resolved itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When splitting your code up between several different scripts, you need to make sure that they are in the correct order if one depends on the other. For example, if one binds to an event, and another triggers an event, you'll want to make sure that the one binding to the event is included first if the event happens immediately, otherwise the event will happen before the event handler is in place.